# Vectorized numpy 1-d reclassification

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, classification, vectorization

I have a large numpy 1-d containing about 700,000 classes. In addition, I have another similar sized array which contains the new values of the classes.

**Example arrays**

```
original_classes = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,10])
new_classes = np.array([1,0,1,2,2,10,1,6,6,9,5,12])
```

**Desired output**

```
>>> reclassify_function(original_classes, new_classes)
array([ 1,  1,  1,  1,  1, 12,  1,  1,  9, 12, 12])
```

The difficulty is that there are multiple class relations.

*Original class 1 should get a new value of 0, which means that 0 and 1 are equal classes and all occurrences of these values should be assigned to the same new class number. Original class 2 should be classified as 1, which means that class 2 is equal to class 0 and 1. Original class 0-2 should thus be assigned to the same new class number etc...*

As I am working with huge arrays I would like the reclassify function to be vectorized.

Comment: Arrays of 70,000 items? It is not huge at all. Try an implementation with loops. When you have it right and if you are not satisfied with performance, post it here.

Comment: Im sorry, should be 700,000. Already working on the loop methods!

Comment: Which will take roughly 2.7MB in memory. Still not that big.

Comment: In your example, 1 becomes 0 and 0 becomes 1.  How is that not an infinite loop?

Comment: I just tried to point out that 0 and 1 (and 2 and 6) are the same class. It does not really matter which new class number they get assigned to. For a code example you can look dat the unvectorized approach.

Comment: Is it 700,000 classes or 700,000 items each with a class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csgraph.connected_components.html) to relabel your classes. For your example data:

```
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import connected_components

A = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5, 6,7,8,9,10,10])
B = np.array([1,0,1,2,2,10,1,6,6,9,5 ,12])

N = max(A.max(), B.max()) + 1
weights = np.ones(len(A), int)
graph = csr_matrix((weights, (A, B)), shape=(N, N))
n_remaining, mapping = connected_components(graph, directed=False)
print mapping[A]
```

Gives:

```
[0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 2 1 1]
```

These are the relabeled classes. I'm sure you can figure out how to express these in terms of the input data. Note for best performance the "original" and "new" classes should be a single range of consecutive integers without gaps.

Comment: Nice! Even with non consecutive values this method relabels the classes correctly. Are you sure that they need to be consecutive?

Comment: @Wilmar - It's for best performance. In my code, `mapping` will be an array of length `N`, so if the input has billions of unused classed it will be a much larger array than necessary and thus inefficient. A few small gaps won't affect the performance to much. But then the `n_remaining` also includes the unused classes and `mapping[A]` isn't consecutive either, most likely.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a vectorized solution, and took about an hour on my laptop.  This creates a list of sets call `class_sets`; each set is a collection of equivalent classes.

```
original_classes = np.random.randint(0,20000,700000)
new_classes = np.random.randint(0,20000,700000)
pairs = zip(original_classes, new_classes)
class_sets = [set(next(pairs))]

for i,p in enumerate(pairs):
    ps = set(p)
    intsect = [ps.intersection(cs) for cs in class_sets]
    if any([ps.intersection(cs) for cs in class_sets]):
        index = np.argmax(intsect)
        class_sets[index] = class_sets[index].union(ps)
    else:
        class_sets.append(ps)
```

Comment: Thanks, tomorrow I will test my method and compare it to your result!

Comment: Your method gives an error so I haven't test it out